# 10 boys plan a camp and have sufficient food for 14 days, if 3 boys are ill and cannot go, howlong will the food now last?

Tags: ratio

Im working on ratios for GCSE, I've become comfortable increasing/decreasing ratios and sharing values based on ratios but Im not sure how to proceed with this type of question.

Intially I thought along the lines of 10/14 to calculate the amount of 'foods' for each child. Then multiple that by 3 to get the value of food for the boys that dont come and add that to the 14 however, my materials tell me the answer should be 20days. So this method is clearly not correct.

Any help on the correct method would be appreciated

Comment: What would have lasted 7 days will now last 10.

Comment: Im not sure how that is helpful, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Hint:  suppose each boy eats $x$ per day.  Then how much do $10$ boys eat in $14$ days?  That tells you how much food you have (in $x$ units) and that should be enough to solve the problem

Comment: There were 10 people, now there are 7. So the time food lasts will change in the inverse proportion.

Comment: It depends on the kind of food. If the food expire at the 14 days then it will be the same independently of the ill childs.

Comment: Ok think ive got this, so the original ration would have been 10:14 this has decreased to 7:10 so 14 / 7 = 2 x 10 = 20 ?

Comment: It was x:10=14. Now it's x:7=? So x=140. Find the ?

Comment: It really helps to use dimensional analysis on this one. Dimensional analysis attaches the units (such as boys, days, etc.) to each quantity when performing calculations. For example 10 boys * 14 days = 140 boy-days worth of food. Then how many days does 140 boy-days of food last with 7 boys? The only way to get days from this is divide boys-days by boys. So 140 boy-days / 7 boys = 20 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, notice that $\frac{10}{14}$ is not food per child, but rather child per day.

The important ratio here is not food per child, or day per child or anything like that. Its the amount of children before and after the illness. It is also important to note that number of children and days are inversely proportional. Meaning that if the number of boys goes up, number of days go down.
So:
$$\frac{days\ after\ illness}{days\ before\ illness}=\frac{boys\ before\ illness}{boys\ after \ illness}$$
$$\frac{days\ after\ illness}{14}=\frac{10}{7}$$ by $14$.

Simply put, you want to scale the ratio $\frac{10}{7}$
$$days\ after\ illness=14\cdot\frac{10}{7}=20$$

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the method i followed and is explained well.

Answer (score 0):

At the rate 10 people eat it would've lasted 14 days. But now there are only 7 to feed:

$\dfrac{10}{7}\times14=20$

Answer (score 0):

10 boys * 3 meal/boy-day * 14 day = 420 meals

7 boys * 3 meal/boy-day * x day = 420 meals

21x =420

x = 20 days

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

"UNIT_OF_FOOD"...that supports one boy for one day

"ALL"... all the food that we have available

"X"... number of days we'll last now

so...

14 * 10 * UNIT_OF_FOOD = ALL

X * 7 * UNIT_OF_FOOD = ALL

14 * 10 * UNIT_OF_FOOD = X * 7 * UNIT_OF_FOOD

14 * 10 = X * 7

X = 20